# Aligning note text to the left in a regression table produced by R (etable)

Tags: alignment, r, tablenotes

My R function (etable) provides me with the following latex table:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\tabularnewline\midrule\midrule
Dependent Variables:&Earnings&Employment\\
Model:&(1) & (2)\\
\midrule \emph{Variables}&   &  \\
Post&-0.0129 & -0.0258\\
  &(0.0022) & (0.0015)\\
Post $\times $ Treat&-0.0987 & -0.0617\\
  &(0.0074) & (0.0043)\\
Outcome mean & 1 & 0.9700\\
\midrule \emph{Fixed-effects}&   &  \\
Person$\times$Event Year (82,405) & Yes & Yes\\
Age (26) & Yes & Yes\\
\midrule \emph{Fit statistics}&  & \\
Observations & 1,349,627&1,349,627\\
R$^2$ & 0.43976&0.29319\\
Within R$^2$ & 0.00811&0.00818\\
\midrule\midrule\multicolumn{3}{l}{\emph{One-way (Establishment) standard-errors in parentheses}}\\
\end{tabular}

\medskip \emph{Notes:} Each column reports the OLS regression results from Equation (3) with different outcomes. The unit of observation is the person-year. Earnings are measured by dividing total labor income with period 0 earnings. Employment is binary and takes the value 1 if the individual is employed during the last week of the year. The post-period indicator includes 7 years after the event and 5 years before the event. The event year is omitted from the estimation sample.
```

The problem is that when compiled, the "notes" section is centered as shown below. How do I need to modify the latex output to align the text to left? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  With the information you provided so far, I can't reproduce the output you get, as the code you currently include does not contain anything related to horizontally centereing contents. Please prepare a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce your issue.